# DATETIME Column in Table, Form for Same Table, Best Way to Include Date and Time for Records

Tags: mysql

I am going to make a form for this table. When I do the `INSERT INTO` php to process the form, do I need to include something for the order_date column? I know I need to leave out the id column because it is automatically generated... (`AUTO_INCREMENT`). Does the same thing go for order_date? I know I do not want the user entering the date info.

```
CREATE TABLE `store_orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `order_first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `order_last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `order_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order_city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `order_state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `order_zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `order_tel` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `order_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cc_type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cc_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `cc_expmonth` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `cc_expyear` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `cc_cvc` varchar(3) NOT NULL
)
```

If there does need to be a field for it on the form page, what is the PHP I can place there to generate the date and time that will get inserted along with the other values? Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.  One is to format the current date/time in PHP.  I don't really like that option.

Another is to use `now()` (or a similar function) when you insert:

```
insert into store_orders ( . . . )
    values (. . ., now(), . . .);
```

And yet another option is to default the value when you create the table:

```
. . .
`order_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
. . .
```

By using the date/time in the database, you are guaranteed consistency for an application that might have multiple users or even a single user that travels around.